# Linking several dependent libraries into my "bare metal" C application

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, arm, static-libraries

I am developing a bare metal C applications on an ST ARM-Cortex-M3. I have also developed libraries that are usable across all these applications.

I used to use Keil ARM-MDK, but want to move over to GNU-GCC. I thus downloaded the latest version of GCC and started recompiling the code.

Although similar questions to this one have been answered, it does not solve my problem ans therefore I am posting my question.

I have a problem with the following:
Lib_Flash has a function Read_Flash(). Lib_AppCfg links in Lib_Flash as it uses Read_Flash().
My application (App) links in both Lib_Flash and Lib_AppCfg. App also uses Read_Flash() for some specific FLASH checks.
In Keil MDK-ARM it worked fine.
With GCC, when functions using Lib_AppCfg are built, I get errors stating that Read_Flash() is an "undefined reference".
I am not sure where the problem lies. Is it in the linking of the Lib_Appcfg is built or is the problem when I link App?

Please advise. If you need additional information, please let me know.

Comment: That is a linking error. Can you show us your compile command?

Comment: Did you try to repeat the `Lib_Flash` library, as in `gcc app.c -o app -lFlash -lAppCfg - lFlash` ?

Comment: @AlexandreC.: The GNU linker can do that somewhat more intelligently using grouping options - see my answer.  That said you "comment" is an answer not a comment on the question, why not post it as one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNU linker by default searches the libraries once in the order listed on the command line.  So if a library later in the list has a reference to symbol defined in an earlier library or object file, then it cannot be resolved.

The simple solution is to use library grouping; this causes the linker to repeatedly search a list of libraries until no further synbols can be resolved. If you are invoking the linker (ld) separately, then the linker options are:

```
--start-group _Flash _AppCfg --end-group
```

or the alternative form

```
-( _Flash _AppCfg -)
```

See the [GNU linker manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/ld/Options.html#Options) for details.  If driving the linker indirectly through gcc you pass linker options via the [-Wl option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html), something like:

```
-Wl,-(,_Flash,_AppCfg,-)
```

I think.

Comment: Thanks Clifford, --start-group and --end-group works great :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you have got an ordering problem in your libraries. Some linkers will rescan all the libraries on the command line till all references are resolved (or can't be resolved). Other linkers work sequentially along the link line.

In particular, this means that if library A defines a symbol SYM_A and library B which comes after library A references this symbol, it won't be resolved on the 2nd type of linker, and your link will fail.

To get round this, you can do one or more of the following

1. Reorder the libraries
2. Replicate libraries on the link line where
   necessary
3. Refactor your libraries so there aren't mutual
   dependencies between them (that is A references symbol SYMB, which
   is defined in B, but B references SYMA)